# Postfix - Auth restriction with multiple servers

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I'm running two mailservers for one domain. One of them is a Microsoft Exchange server that holds a few mail accounts - and a Postfix one hosted on my Linux server to which mails are relayed from Exchange, if the recipient doesn't exist there.

I would like to use `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` on my Postfix server. I want to make sure, that no one sends emails from adresses that they don't own. Now the problem comes up: it doesn't reject the emails relayed from Exchange, but **it rejects emails sent from Exchange to an account that lies on Postfix**.

I hope it's clear what I mean. I don't even get why this commands verifies incoming mails. All I want to control is outbound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably put the configuration parameter in your `main.cf`, making it a global setting for all smtpd instances.

The instance on port `25` should be handling inbound mail without this setting, while another instance for *submission* on SMTPS port `465` (or `STARTTLS` on `587`) handles outbound mail from your own users. Using the `master.cf` you can add configuration parameters for individual instances.

Comment: Thank you, that was the reason!